# What color to use in owner-draw Windows List Control background?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have an owner-drawn list control in my Windows program. I use CListCtrl::GetBkColor to get the background color, and for a selected item I use GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT). This matches what Windows uses for non owner drawn list controls, except for the case where the control doesn't have focus - then the background is replaced with gray.

Does Windows use one of the GetSysColor constants for the selected but unfocused background? If so, which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COLOR_INACTIVECAPTION` (3), I think.

**Update:**  Nope, it looks like it's just `COLOR_BTNFACE` (15).

Comment: And the text should be COLOR_BTNTEXT. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ok.  With a bit of fiddling, I've determined that it uses the `SystemColors.Control` color in .Net, which is the equivalent of the C++ `COLOR_3DFACE`

`COLOR_BTNFACE`, `COLOR_MENU`, and `COLOR_MENUBAR` all also represent the same color on a default install of Windows.

Comment: A `ListView` behaves like this, with `View` set to `Details` and `HideSelection` set to `false`.

Comment: @MusiGenesis, thanks for filling in the details - you're exactly right.

Comment: COLOR_3DFACE and COLOR_BTNFACE are exactly the same (they both map to the value 15). The others, while they might be the same color initially they are separate values and can be changed independently. Thus the reason for me asking the question.